# AS3 Error accessing parent methods and variables

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm learning AS3 and I understand that there are a bunch of related questions here with this type of error but I can't seem to figure it out.

I'm getting this error:

```
TypeError: Error #1034: Type coercion failed: cannot convert bej_cs5_fla::MainTimeline@330ae041 in Board.
at BoardTimer/gameOver()
at BoardTimer/countdown()
at flash.utils::Timer/_timerDispatch()
at flash.utils::Timer/tick()
```

I have to classes. Class `Board` and class `BoardTimer`.

`Board`:

```
public class Board extends MovieClip {
    //Attributes
    public var boardSide:uint;

    public function Board(dimention:uint) {
                 boardSide = dimention;
        // Code goes here
    }
   }
```

`BoardTimer`:

```
    public class BoardTimer extends Board{

    public function BoardTimer(dimention:uint)
    {
        boardSide2 = dimention;
        super(dimention);
        gameTimerBox = new TextField();
        myTimer = new Timer(1000,count);
        myTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, countdown);
        myTimer.start();
    }
     }
```

And some `BoardTimer` methods:

```
    function countdown(event:TimerEvent):void
    {
        gameTimerBox.x = 700;
        gameTimerBox.y = 200;
        gameTimerBox.textColor = 0xFFFFFF;
        gameTimerBox.text = String((count)-myTimer.currentCount);
        if (gameTimerBox.text == "0")
        {
            gameOver();
            gameTimerBox.text = String("Game Over");
        }
        addChild(gameTimerBox);
    }

    function gameOver()
    {
        trace(Board(parent).boardSide);
    }
```

In one frame I have this:

```
dimention=10;
var boardTimer_mc= new BoardTimer(dimention);
boardTimer_mc.x=25;
boardTimer_mc.y=25;
addChild(boardTimer_mc);
```

and in another I have this:

```
var dimention:uint=10;
var board_mc: Board = new Board(dimention);
board_mc.x=25;
board_mc.y=25;
addChild(board_mc);
```

`BoardTimer` is doing all that `Board`is doing but I'm failing to get access to `Board` methods and variables. I've tried `trace(Board(parent).boardSide);`, `trace(Board(this.parent).boardSide);` and `trace(Board(this.parent.parent).boardSide);` and nothing.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`parent` doesn't refer to base class or the parent class you derived from. It refers to the parent in the displaylist on the stage. (read [this](http://joshblog.net/2007/07/12/disabling-actionscript-3-strict-mode-in-flash-cs3/))

Use [super](http://gamedev.michaeljameswilliams.com/2009/04/03/extends-override-and-super/) keyword for referring to the base class. Also, when you are inheriting the class, all the protected & public methods & variables would be available as it is in the derived class.